# Link docker.sock in /var/run

Tags: docker, sockets, socat

**<TL;DR>**
I have a binary tool that relies on docker UNIX socket `/var/run/docker.sock`
I am running the binary in a Gitlab CI job, thus having a docker on a TCP socket `tcp://docker:2375`
How to bind UNIX socket /var/run/docker.sock with TCP `tcp://docker:2375`?
**</TL;DR>**

**[What I have]**

- I use Gitlab pipelines with Docker-in-Docker. Docker works perfectly
- ````
  ```yml
  services:
    - docker:19-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  ```
  ````
- I use twistcli (PaloAlto/PrismaCloud) to do runtime image scanning

**[The problem]**

- Twistcli looks for UNIX socket `/var/run/docker.sock` (hardcoded in the binary + no cli flag for changing that (see [here](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/prisma/prisma-cloud/21-08/prisma-cloud-compute-edition-admin/runtime_defense/image_analysis_sandbox)))
- Docker daemon is here available with a TCP socket `tcp://docker:2375` (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker))

**[What I tried]**

```
# TEST 1
ln -s tcp://docker:2375 /var/run/docker.sock
./twistcli sandbox image_to_scan
ERROR: Get "http://unix.sock/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory

# TEST 2
touch /var/run/docker.sock
socat -v TCP-LISTEN:docker:2375,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
./twistcli sandbox image_to_scan
ERROR: cannot connect to Docker endpoint

# TEST 3 (@larsks' proposition)
socat -v tcp-connect:docker:2375 unix-listen:/var/run/docker.sock,fork
ERROR: Failed to extract Platform data from docker version: failed to fetch docker api version 'Get "http://unix.sock/version": EOF'
```

**[My question]**

- How to trick the system so /var/run/docker.sock actually points to the tcp://docker:2375 docker.sock ?

Comment: I believe the standard Docker SDKs support a `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable; does setting `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375` help here?

Comment: Hi, thank you for reaching out.
Actually the `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375` is already set and using docker commands works ok.

However using the `twistcli` binary still causes problems as it looks for `/var/run/docker.sock`, thus my question to somehow bind the unix socket to the tcp one

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with your `socat` command, but you have your parameters backwards. You *already* have a Docker daemon listening on port 2375, so you don't want `socat` to listen on that address: You want `socat` to listen on the unix socket, and proxy connections to the TCP socket:

```
socat -v tcp-connect:docker:2375 unix-listen:/var/run/docker.sock,fork
```

With this in place, I can successfully access a TCP-enabled remote docker daemon using a local Unix socket.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help!

Inverting the 2 helps but now I have a `Failed to extract Platform data from docker version: failed to fetch docker api version 'Get "http://unix.sock/version": EOF'`

[./twistcli sandbox 1/2 (gitlab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJaj5.png)
[./twistcli sandbox 2/2 (gitlab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epDlW.png)
(Sorry, `I need 10 reputation to post images`)

Same happened on WSL2 on which I also `socat` the docker.sock:
[./twistcli sandbox 1/1 (wsl2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgns6.png)

EDIT: I did some digging. Using my WSL2 machine with `socat` I am able to run `docker images` and `docker ps`.
However, `docker run` hangs forever + exiting the socat command give an EOF error on the docker run.

[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfbOC.png)
[docker images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJrQJ.jpg)

[docker run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNG1t.jpg)